# Variance of Linear Combination of Independent Bernoulli Distributions

Tags: probability

- $X = \sum_{n}{a_{n}B_{n}}$
- $a_n$ are constants.
- $B_{n}$ are independent random variables following Bernoulli distributions.
- $p_{n} = P(B_{n} = 1)$ and $1 - p_{n} = P(B_{n} = 0)$

Should variance of $X$ be $\sum_{n} a^{2}_{n} p_{n}(1 - p_{n})$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as you can prove using basic properties of the variance. (If you cannot: where are you stuck?)

Comment: Thanks. I just want to make sure this is right. The matrix notation looks interesting. But I will ask why that works in another question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Matrix_notation_for_the_variance_of_a_linear_combination